# Making Django ignore string literals

Tags: django, string-literals

UPDATE 2:  The problem isn't a Django problem at all - Python was definitely stripping out the characters before it got to Django.  The fix is to define the string as raw

```
inputs['variable'] = r'{\bf this is code} \\'
```

UPDATE:  It turns out this is a deeper question than I thought at first glance - the issue is that python is replacing the string literals before they ever get to django.  I will do more investigating and update this if I find a solution.

I'm using django to work with LaTeX templates for report generation, and am running into a lot of problems with the way Django replaces parts of strings.

Specficially, I've run into two problems where I try to insert a variable containing latex code.

The first was that it would replace HTML characters, such as the less than symbol, with their HTML codes, which are of course gibberish to a LaTeX interpreter.  I fixed this by setting the context to never autoescape, like so:

```
c = Context(inputs)
c.autoescape = False
```

However, I still have my second issue, which is that Django replaces string literals with their corresponding characers, so a double backslash becomes \, and \b becomes a backspace.  How can I force Django to leave these characters in place, so

```
inputs['variable'] = '{\bf this is code} \\'
```

won't get mangled when I use

```
{{variable}}
```

to reference it in the django template?

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the updates above, it wasn't a problem with Django at all - Python was interpreting the string literals before the string even made it to Django.  The fix was to define the string as raw.

```
inputs['variable'] = r'{\bf this is code} \\'
```